# D3.JS Recalculate datum() values based on input change

Tags: d3.js

I am using this code to draw a line based on input data:

```
const line = d3.line()
  .x((d) => x(d[0]))
  .y((d) => d[1]);

const lineObjects = view.append('g')
    .selectAll("g")
      .data(input)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .append('path')
    .datum((d)=> [
  [d.value*3, d.value2],
  [d.value*10, d.value3],
  [d.value*3, d.value4],
  ])
    .attr('d', line)
```

Which works great on first run. 
My problem is that I don't know how to redraw those lines on `input` change. If I call lineObjects.datum() again then instead of normal input I get the previous function return result.

Comment: `d` is not a valid `g` attribute

Comment: @rioV8 my bad, added the path attribute

Comment: why need a `g`?